# WebStorm will resolve '.' to './index.js' but not './'

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I've recently switched to WebStorm 2017.3 from another editor, it's pretty decent with the exception of a few teething problems that I've managed to sort, all with the exception of one.

When I go to import a component into a file using `'./'` (a test file in this case) in the same directory, throws me a yellow squiggly. If I use `'.'` then everything is all good in the hood.  I'm on a legacy codebase so I can't change all the imports to this.

```
import GroupFooter from './' // throws me an error.
import GroupFooter from '.' // is all good.
```

I've tried switching the 'use directory import when index.js is available' but still no joy.  Does anybody have any ideas as to how to get WebStorm to recognise `'./'` as a viable path?  *It should be noted that webpack has no trouble resolving this, nor does the test runner that runs the file.

[image]

Comment: File a bug with IntelliJ? Or turn off import inspections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks similar to [WEB-30209](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30209) that is fixed in most recent update. Please try upgrading Webstorm